# Alert User- Activemq camel

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have an application working with activemq and camel

In my Application, Consumer of activemq is initially at running stage so it will consume if there is message in Activemq and process it. If there is any failure in business logic the message will be redeliver for given number of times, after re delivery message for given times the message will go to `DLQ(DeadLetterQueue)`. Now what I want is to alert user by send him mail before the message go to DLQ.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

as suggested, just update your Camel exception handling to first send the email, then route to the DLQ...

```
onException(Exception.class).handled(true).process(new MyAlertProcessor()).to(DLQ);
```

use `handled(false)` if you'd rather propagate the error back to ActiveMQ instead of handling in your Camel exception clause, etc.